# Function with 3 arguments to create a prepend element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

it's my first time posting a question here, sorry if I say something strange. I am currently studying Javascript. I just tried to create a function that has 3 arguments, a Parent element, the element to be created, and the text or content that will go inside it. The text is added just fine but the second argument which is meant for creating the element doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the function I tried to create

```
const newFirstChild = function(el,newEl,elContent){
    const selectElement = (parentElement) => document.querySelector(el);
    const newElement = (createElement) => document.createElement(newEl);
    newEl = newEl.innerText = elContent;
    selectElement(el,newEl).prepend(newEl);
}
```

I wanted to make something like: the function will get the Parent element, the element to be added, and the content that will go inside. I tried to add a new bolded text for example, the text is added but is not bolded.
Did I do something wrong? Or is it not possible to do this at all?

Comment: WHY are you making function in functions? Code is 100x more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I'm still learning, I tried to fix it on the self answer bellow, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things going on in the function you posted that are wrong or just don't make sense.

For example, you created a function called `newElement` that never gets called:

```
const newElement = (createElement) => document.createElement(newEl);
```

Another question is, why do you need to create a new element when you already have a reference to the new element? If you have a reference to it, then it's already been created. Perhaps you are trying to **copy** the element that `newEl` points to?

In your question, is `newEl` a string? If so, then you can create the new element with the following function:

```
function myFunction(parent, childType, text){
    const child = document.createElement(childType);
    parent.prepend(child);
    child.innerText = text;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
myFunction(document.getElementById("parentElem"), "div", "hello world");
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I guess I ended up lost, first time I try something like this. Your code helped me a lot, very much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Changed a few things according to the answer, and it ended up like this:

```
    const newFirstChild = function(el,newEl,elContent){
        const parentElement = document.querySelector(el);
        const child = document.createElement(newEl);
        child.innerText = elContent;
        parentElement.prepend(child);
    }
```

I called the function like this:
`newFirstChild('p','b','sample text')`
It adds a new bold text as a child of the paragraph